# Why does FetchType.Eager prevent org.hibernate.TransientObjectException in bidirectional mapping while CascadeType.ALL has no effect?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

After populating a form backing bean (status) with data inside a .jsp I try to add it to its parent entity (employee). Unfortunately, this results in an org.hibernate.TransientObjectException.

Adding the CascadeType.ALL to the @ManyToOne (owning side, Status.java) as proposed in some threads has no effect, which should be correct. But adding fetch = FetchType.EAGER on the @OneToMany (referencing side, Employee.java) in addition to the CascadeType.ALL solves the issue (as shown below in the code).

Model "Employee"

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Status> statusList = new ArrayList<Status>();

public void addStatus(Status status) {
    this.statusList.add(status);
    status.setEmployee(this);
 }
}
```

Model "Status"

```
@Entity
public class Status implements Comparable<Status> {

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
private Employee employee;

}
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class DashboardController {

@PostMapping("addStatus")
public String addStatus(@Valid @ModelAttribute("newStatus") Status newStatus Principal principal) {

Employee employee = employeeService.getEmployeeByPosition(principal.getName());
        employee.addStatus(newStatus);
        employeeService.updateEmployee(employee);
 }
}
```

Service

```
@Service
public class EmployeeService {
public void updateEmployee(Employee employee) {
    employeeRepo.save(employee);
 }
}
```

I expected that the CascadeType.ALL on the @OneToMany side would be sufficient. But this results in

*HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: ....model.Status]*

On the other hand, the exception is gone when I use FetchType.EAGER in addition, which I cant comprehend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely:

```
Employee employee = employeeService.getEmployeeByPosition(principal.getName());
```

This happens in **Transaction 1**.

```
employee.addStatus(newStatus);
```

Here entity is already in a detached state and without eager the `LAZY` loading will not work from this point.

```
employeeService.updateEmployee(employee);
```

Here in **Transaction 2**, you are trying to, most likely internally `merge`, but the collection has not been lazy-loaded. With `EAGER` it is and the merge succeeds.

Comment: Shouldn't this cause a null pointer exception if the `statusList` collection is not loaded ?

Comment: It should throw a lazy init exception, thats true.

Comment: But it doesnt :( I tried putting all logic from the Controller inside the service-method and added @Transactional with no success.
Is anything wrong with the app-flow? Can i provide any additional helpfull information?
Right now i kept the Lazy-Fetching and saved the status via a new StatusService (which calls a StatusReposittory) right before calling

 `employeeService.updateEmployee(employee);`    to make it work.

What would be the recommed way to handle it?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski you were right! The reason why the LazyInitializationException was not thrown was that by default spring boot uses the Open Session In View Pattern. Once i set `spring.jpa.open-in-view=false` in application.properties the Exception will be thrown.